# Chart JS Manual Bar Chart YAxis

Tags: chart.js

I am working on a project that will use ratings from 1-10.  The automatic scaling in `ChartJs` is causing issues where data is not displayed due to it not being in range.

How can I remove the automatic scaling of a bar chart yxais and manually set the scales to 1-10 ?

```
<canvas id="bar-chart-grouped" width="800" height="350"></canvas>
<script>
    new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart-grouped"), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: [{% for result in results %}
                  "{{result.title}}",
              {% endfor %}],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Rating",
          backgroundColor: "#3e95cd",
          data: [{% for result in results %}
                  "{{result.w_average}}",
              {% endfor %}]
        }, {
          label: "My Rating",
          backgroundColor: "#3cba9f",
          data: [{% for result in results %}
                  "{{result.rating}}",
              {% endfor %}]
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Movie Ratings'
      }
    }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I made some minor formatting improvements. Hope you get a good answer ;)